# Unit test doesn't execute loop how it should

Tags: c#, unit-testing, selenium

what I want the code to do is basically simple, I want it to go to **all** articles and selects **all** article ratings and then parse the returned rating into an int, and then checks (on a checkbox in each article) the articles that has a rating of 5 or higher, and I want it to check maximally ten articles.
the code is below:

```
string notes =  driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//article[*]/div/div[1]/div/div/span"))
    .Text.Replace(" notes", "");//here I just had to remove the word notes from the rating in order to use this variable. 
int Notes = int.Parse(notes);
int article = 0;
if (Notes >= 5)
{
    do //>--the number of articles selected
    {
        driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//article[*]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]")).Click();
        article = article + 1;
    } while (article < 10);
}
```

what actually happens is that it checks the first articles ten times(or better said it checks **and** unchecks the checkbox five times), and then it proceeds with the rest of test, so can anyone tell me how to fix it.

**modification** 
I changed the code (which isn't working) :

```
int post = 1;
int posted = 0;
var Xpath_post = string.Format("//article[{1}]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]", post);
string notes = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(Xpath_post)).Text.Replace(" notes", "");
int Notes;
Notes = int.Parse(notes);
        do
        {
            if (Notes >= 5)
            {
                driver.FindElement(By.XPath(Xpath_post)).Click();
                posted = post;
                post = post + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                post = post + 1;
            }
        } while (posted < 10);
```

still need help!

okay once again I was given a helpful tip to improve my code so here is my latest update, I replaced (in the second code) this line:
`var Xpath_post = string.Format("//article[{1}]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]", post);`
with the following two lines:
`string post1 = post.ToString();
string Xpath_post = string.Format("//article[{0}]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]", post1);`   so why did I do that, @PHeiberg made the comment that the change on the `post`variable won't change the string `Xpath_post` since the variable is not part of the built string. now I thought why don't we see if I can find a way to solve this issue and guess what I wasn't able to fix it, shocker right?!

anyway it would be great if somebody could help thanks.

Comment: It doesn't look like your `int article` is being used anywhere to move to the next element. Did you mean to do something like `String.Format("//{0}[]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]", article)` for the XPath?

Comment: yes you are right it's not moving to the next element. as for your suggestion I tried it but was forced to make changes on the code, but the new code isn't working at all, please have a look at it and tell me if you can fix it or help me with it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright here is the solution :

```
        int post = 1;
        int posted = 0;
        do
        {
            var post1 = post.ToString();
            string xpathnotes = $"//article[{post1}]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/span";
            string notes = _driver.FindElement(By.XPath(xpathnotes)).Text.Replace(" notes", "");
            if (int.Parse(notes) >= 5)
            {
                string xpathcheck = $"//article[{post1}]/div/div[2]/div/a";
                _driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("xpathcheck")).Click();

                posted = posted + 1;
                post = post + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                post = post + 1;
            }
        } while (posted < 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//article[*]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]")).Click();
```

needs to use the article index, in order to get the correct article in the while loop. Replace it with:

```
var expression = string.Format("//article[{0}]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]", article);
driver.FindElement(By.XPath(expression)).Click();
```

to build the appropriate xpath expression for each article.

The problem with your edited code is that you build the `Xpath_post` once in the beginning. Making a change to the `post` variable will not change that string, since the variable is not part of the built string.

Comment: any tips on how to make any change to the `post` variable affect the `Xpath_post` string?

Comment: Look at my suggested code. Build the entire xpath expression once per loop. In your first example, replace the entire `driver.FindElement`-line with my two lines.

Comment: I did replace that line with the two other lines but it didn't work, I replaced them in the first code, any ideas on how to fix the second one. thanks